# google map api v3 Weather information

Tags: google-maps-api-3, yahoo-weather-api

How do we add the weather overlay option to a Google map, just like on Google my maps?
I've searched for it, but i can't find the answer.

Do i have to call a weather web service?

Comment: WeatherLayer is no longer available http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/sunsetting-javascript-api-weather-panoramio.html

Comment: Google seems to recommend using Open Weather Map, as of 2015. https://github.com/google/maps-for-work-samples/blob/master/samples/maps/OpenWeatherMapLayer/OpenWeatherMapLayer.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display the WeatherLayer[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#WeatherLayer) on your map by taking two steps:

First, load the WeatherLayer library by adding the `libraries` parameter to the URL you use to load the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Then, you must create an instance of the `google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherLayer) class, passing any options in a `WeatherLayerOptions`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherLayerOptions) object, and attach the `WeatherLayer` to the map:

```
var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
  temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
});
weatherLayer.setMap(map);
```

In addition to the WeatherLayer, there is also a separate `google.maps.weather.CloudLayer`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CloudLayer) class that you may create in a similar way:

```
var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
cloudLayer.setMap(map);
```

There is no separate library that you must load to use the CloudLayer; adding the `libraries=weather` parameter to the URL that loads the map makes both the WeatherLayer and the CloudLayer available on your map. There as a [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Weather Layer](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather), that shows the usage of both layers.

Answer (score 2):

I have got same trouble when I tried to use Google map apiv3 with weather layer. But luckily, I found this site **http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/** that provides all Google map api v3 samples and they are worked. Hope this help.

Cuong Vo